# Specify icon for pdf file

Tags: pdftex, icon

When having a pdf file it has always the same icon (in my case I see always:
[image])
I would like to be able to have the possibility to specify the icon by means of an `.ico` file (or any other image) in the part directly after `\documentclass` or in the `\begin{document} ...` end{document}` part.

I've been searching the net for this possibility but didn't find anything.
I did find something about favicon but I think this more geared to HTML and net access.

Is this possible? any pointers welcome.

**Edit**

Based on the comments it looks like the requested feature is not really possible./
When looking at HTML files it is possible to add a line like:

```
<link rel="icon" href="$relpath^my_icon.ico" type="image/x-icon" />
```

which will give a tab an icon, the OS will still show something like [image]
in the file / directory viewer.

When "translating" this to pdf where we have e.g.:

[image]

So here we have 2 positions with a potential icon:

1. top line with a pdf icon, this identifies the program (and we should leave it as it is).
2. line "Home" Tools" "amsldoc.pdf" would be nice when an icon would be in front of the word "amsldoc.pdf".

Still it would have been nice to to have the possibility to have it also on the file / directory viewer (like can be done for individual executable with a RC file that is bound into executable, at least under Windows (MSVC compiler) and Cygwin (GCC compiler)).

**Edit 2**

I was thinking about this a bit and remembered the usage of settings like `pdftitle`, `pdfauthor`, `pdfkeywords` etc. of the hyperref package. Checking the possible keywords there is nothing for including an icon.
I also saw something like `PTEX.Fullbanner` which looks like to be related to `\pdfinfo` (seen in the pdftex-a manual) but here there is also no mentioning of an icon.

Comment: That would be cool.  I don't think it's possible on Windows.  https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/forum/all/how-to-change-pdf-file-icon-to-another-icon/4019d851-92a0-4c54-8a63-3bca841ea366

Comment: Which operating system are you using? In macOS you can choose "Get Info" from the files context menu, click on the icon on the top left and then paste whatever image you like there.

Comment: Yes there is the possibility to change all icons on a system, but that is just for that machine / user. My intention is (as you understood) to have it on a file basis.

Comment: @samcarter_is_at_topanswers.xyz  I would like to have the possibility for all OS

Comment: @albert I added how this can be done in macOS to my comment. However icons are controlled by the operating system, so this does not sounds like a latex problem. Maybe better suited for superusers.com ?

Comment: @samcarter_is_at_topanswers.xyz I'm not using MacOS but I would like to have a possibility to do it in a transparent way for all OS. Question remains is this a property on the MacOS just for the current user for all MacOS users that get the pdf? In other words where is it stored?

Comment: It is for the current user. Icons are generated by the OS, not from the file.

Comment: As @samcarter_is_at_topanswers.xyz says, whether an icon is shown at all and, if so, which icon, is determined by the software displaying the file rather than the file. The icon you see doesn't belong to the PDF. It's added by your system software. Note that even if you could pack the icon into the PDF, the result wouldn't be cross-platform as you desire because different systems use different icon formats. Moreover, some systems use multiple files, while others use only one. (On Linux, an icon typically has multiple PNGs for different sizes. ICNS and ICO combine the sizes into a single file.)

Comment: @cfr I compare the situation with the HTML, here you can add `<link rel="icon" href="$relpath^my_icon.ico" type="image/x-icon" />` and this is picked up by the browser (checked with Chrome, FireFox, Edge). Each HTML file can have its own icon. When the possibility would exists in a pdf file the viewer could / would decide what to do with the information.

Comment: @albert I realise that, but there's no equivalent of an HTML standard covering both free and proprietary platforms when it comes to file selection dialog boxes, file managers etc. Even for applications, which often do come with their own icons, the way they do that differs between systems. (Mac applications are bundles of files; Linux doesn't even have applications in that sense.)

Comment: @cfr looks like I actually I want something different from what I wrote, thanks for making me aware of it, I'll update the question).

Comment: The features you're asking for are functions of your window manager (the icon you do have) and your PDF viewer (the icon you don't have). In my PDF viewer, I have icons to the left of the file names on the tabs. In my PDF viewer, an icon for the file's type (PDF) appears to the left of the name on each tab representing an open file. This icon doesn't appear at the top of the window, though an icon identifying the application (which is distinct from the icon representing the file type) does appear there. This is due to: choice of window manager, choice of PDF viewer and configuration choices.

Comment: None of this is in any way related to TeX.